# Nailing a joist hanger to ledger with concrete behind

Tags: joists, ledger

So I've got a 2x10 Ledger attached to a concrete wall. I have a double 2x10 joist that needs to connect to the ledger. I have a joist hanger for this but the installation requirements say to use 16d nails (which are typically 3 1/2" long) to connect to the ledger. How can I do that if the ledger is only 1 1/2" thick? Will the nail go into the concrete? Are there shorter nails?

Comment: FYI, joist hangers are almost never installed with 16d nails. They're usually hung with "teco" nails, as described in the answers below. They're roughly as thick as 16d nails, but of a length appropriate for a single two-by ledger.

Comment: 16d on a 2× not heard of that before, Teco yes.

Answer (score 1):

Joist hangers resist loads in shear, not withdrawal. While a 16d is more common, full resistance is developed in a 2x.

Simpson Strong-Tie makes a [short nail](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000WI84VM) that is 1 1/2” long x 9 ga. diameter.

Oh, and be sure to order the nails treated (galvanized) or stainless steel based on the type of pressure treated ledger.

Comment: 16d are not more common. It would be a massive effort to put 8-12 full-size framing nails in dozens or hundreds of hangers by hand. Almost everyone uses nails like those you've described, except in some girder situations. We call them "teco" nails, probably after an early manufacturer.

Comment: @isherwood you are correct about the Tico nail origins. https://www.hansenpolebuildings.com/2013/01/tico-10d-common-nails/

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean TICO ???? I’m talking Simpson. Where did TICO come from?

Comment: @LeeSam did you not read the comment directly above mine?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Exactly. My “Answer” referred to Simpson and now Isherwood and you are concerned about Tico. Why?

Comment: I'm not concerned. Isherwood made a comment on them being called Teco/Tico an I had never heard the term; I thought it was interesting enough to respond

Answer (score 1):

There are shorter nails, but there are also short screws available.  I'd go with the screws every time.  For example [these](https://www.strongtie.com/strongdrive_exteriorwoodscrews/sd_screw/p/strong-drive-sd-connector-screw) are made by Simpson and fully approved for use with their hangers.

Note that the #10 screws are the correct size to replace 16d nails.